# ReadAsync exiting, not able to trace in debug

Tags: c#, async-await

I have the following code (`_ns` is a NetworkStream)

```
await GetResponse(_ns);
btnSend.Enabled = true;

private async Task GetResponse(NetworkStream stream)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var readBuffer = new byte[4096];
        var asyncReader = await stream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
        txtBoxMessagesIn.Text += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuffer.ToArray()) + Environment.NewLine;
        if (asyncReader <= 0) break;
    }
}
```

I seem to fill the entire buffer with what I expect, but btnSend is never enabled.

When I run it in debug mode, my while loop runs a couple of times, I see `asyncReader` get set to different values but it never equals 0 to break the loop as I expect, it justs exits at the line:

```
var asyncReader = await stream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
```

without generating any errors. What is causing this? Do I need to set something in Visual Studio to break on this type of error?

Comment: Non-related errors: `readBuffer` is already an array, you don't need to call `readBuffer.ToArray()`, but you should use the value `asyncReader` there.

Comment: Possibly nothing to do with your problem, but shouldn't that test `if asyncReader <= 0)` be before you try to extract the contents?

Comment: `NetworkStream` is not like other streams. You cannot use it this way.

Comment: @GaryMcGill You're right, but it doesn't get to that part of the code before something makes it exit.

Comment: I suspect nothing closes the network communication - so you never endup  with reading 0 bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReadAsync` will only return `0` when the stream *ends*. This is how all streams work. If the stream has not ended (i.e., for a socket stream, the socket is still open), then `ReadAsync` will (asynchronously) wait for the stream to either read more bytes or end.

I assume that the other end of the socket is just hanging open but not sending any more data. In this case, any stream reads will just wait for it to either send more bytes or close. There's no exceptions - this is not an exceptional situation. Since the socket is not closed, the stream read will not return `0`, and so your `while` loop will not exit.

Comment: Out of interest, would you know what is causing the exit? I would have thought that it would, as you state, loop forever, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Family: What makes you think it exits? If it exited, the task would complete and the button would be enabled.

Comment: This is the first time I've tried using async and await. I don't fully understand it. I was just confused by the debug process, it doesn't continuously step through the while loop, it just appears to finish. I assume that's because there's nothing left in the stream. I shall read further on the process.

Comment: @Family: The debugger experience can be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You can either wrap the call to ReadAsync in a try/catch statement or check the result of the task. I would go with try/catch approach to at least see what's going on initially.

```
try { var asyncReader = await stream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length); }
catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Other approach would be the following, but you can't be sure if ReadAsync ends gracefully when exception occurs.

```
var task = stream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
task.Start();
if (task.Exception != null)
   // see what's going here
```

Comment: I still don't seem to get an exception. It's most odd.